# TI-84: Same formula, same inputs, different answers when using program v.s. home screen

Tags: math, calculator, ti-basic

I wanted to write a simple formula in TI-Basic to calculate compound interest for my TI-84 calculator. The formula for compound interest is `A = P(1+(r/n))^(n)(t)` where `p` is the principal amount, `r` is the interest rate (expressed as a decimal), `n` is the number of times the principal is compounded, `t` is the amount of time, and `a` is your final amount with interest added.

When I set variables (see below) and and type the formula in **exactly** how it is above on my calculators home screen, I get *$7332.86*, which is the correct answer.

However, when I set the variables and type the formula in as a program (see below), I get **$42684.69**, which is **not** correct.

I have tried this program on 2 different TI-84 calculators and I have gotten the same results, so it is not something with my calculator.

I am honestly stumped. I have no idea why this is happening, so if you are good at math, know how to program a ti series calculator, or just see a mistake that I am missing, please tell me because this thing has been driving me crazy!

**Program with same inputs and formula but gives different answer than when used on the home screen:**

```
: 2000 -> P
: 0.065 -> R
: 54 -> N
: 20 -> T
: P(1+(R/N))^(N)(T) -> A
: Disp A
```

Comment: Is that just a typo or are you using K where you should be using N?

Comment: yeah that's just a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know what the problem you are facing is, but I think your program should look like this:

```
Prompt P
Prompt R
Prompt N
Prompt T

Disp P(1+(R/N))^(NT)
```

---

**EDIT**

I think you need an extra set of parentheses. `^(N)(T)` only raises to the power of `N`, and then multiplies by `T`. Try `^((N)(T))` or simply `^(NT)`.

Comment: I just tried that and got the same exact wrong value `42684.69'.

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks so much, this stupid error has been driving me crazy for days!

Answer (score 1):

You're formula is equivalent to `T*P*((1+(R/N))^(N))`, which is obviously wrong. The reason it's doing this is because of the order of operations. Try `P*(1+(R/N))^(T*N)`

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of the code (if you want to conserve memory space):

:promptP,R,N,T

:Disp P(1+(R/N))^(NT)

Happy coding!